# run two luigi WrapperTasks successively

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

```py
import luigi as li


class TaskA(li.Task):

    def output(self):
        return li.LocalTarget('TaskA.txt')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('DONE_A')


class TaskB(li.Task):
    required_task = li.TaskParameter()

    def output(self):
        return li.LocalTarget('TaskB.txt')

    def requires(self):
        return self.required_task

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('DONE_B')


class TaskC(li.Task):

    def output(self):
        return li.LocalTarget('TaskC.txt')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('DONE_C')


class PipelineX(li.WrapperTask):

    def requires(self):
        task_a = TaskA()
        return TaskB(required_task=task_a)


class PipelineY(li.WrapperTask):

    def requires(self):
        return TaskC()


class AllPipelines(li.?):
    pipeline_x = li.TaskParameter(default=PipelineX())
    pipeline_y = li.TaskParameter(default=PipelineY())

    # problem: PipelineY depends on PipelineX
    # how to first run pipeline_x, wait until it finished, then
    # run pipeline_y? Afterwards AllPipelines should complete.
```

Hello community,

I am looking for a way to run multiple (currently WrapperTasks) successively.

I tried to break down my problem in the sample-code above and would be really glad if somebody can give me some hints on how to manage it.

The goal is following:

1. run `PipelineX`
2. when 1. is `completed()`, run `PipelineY`
3. when all are done, complete `AllPipelines`

Thank you all so much for any help!

Best regards

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since you say that `PipelineY` depends on `PipelineX`, the most natural thing would be to include `PipelineX` in the requires of `PipelineY`:

```
def PipelineY(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        return [PipelineY, TaskC]
```

However, I bet that it is actually `TaskC` that depends on `PipelineY`, so you could put `PipelineY` into `TaskC`'s dependencies.

If you truly need a pipeline though, and the above doesn't work for you, you can use `luigi`'s dynamic dependencies (https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies):

```
def AllPipelines(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("success.txt")

    def run(self):
        yield PipelineX()
        yield PipelineY()
        with self.output().open('w') as out_file:
            out_file.write("1")
```